# Poor performing case statement with IS_SRVROLEMEMBER

Tags: sql

We are trying to mask some data in our Warehouse using a case statement:

```
   SELECT CASE WHEN IS_SRVROLEMEMBER('ServerRoleName') = 1 THEN Field ELSE '****' 
   FROM TBL
```

I can't think of any other way to accomplish this, but didn't think it would impact performance.

Comment: What dbms is this? How poorly is it performing? Can you post a (picture of the) actual execution plan taken?

Comment: MS SQL Server 2012 is the platform, I am not sure that this is the issue but our vendor is blaming that statement.  Sadly I can not add an image because it would be a HIPAA violation :(

Comment: Hm, one thing you could try is outsource that select into a variable `@issrvrolemember BIT = (...)` and then check that variable instead, I think it may be the case this gets executed for every row which would not be very efficient/useful indeed :)

Comment: Good idea, I will give that a shot and let you know!